# How to can I make the app not read device id?

Tags: android, permissions, device, imei

How can I make my android app not see my phone device id, IMEI, and other information. How can I hide it from the app? Without rooting the phone

Comment: If this is your app, simply remove the code that attempts to access the phone device ID, IMEI, and other information.

Comment: It's not my app unfortunately